# How to log/see the traffic going through stunnel before/after encryption?

Tags: stunnel

So I am using stunnel to talk to a SSL server. I would like to see the messages I am sending before they get encrypted and more importantly the messages I am receiving after they get decrypted.

I turned on debug logging (level 7) but I still can't see the messages. Below the details:

stunnel.conf

```
output = coinsetter.log

[remote]
client = yes
accept = 8888
connect = 198.61.189.25:5001
debug = 7
```

stunnel output:

```
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.18 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 platform
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:SELECT,IPv6 TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file coinsetter.conf
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG4[ui]: Authentication is needed to prevent MITM attacks
2015.09.23 23:11:17 LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful


2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: Service [remote] started
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG5[0]: Service [remote] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:57261
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: failover: round-robin
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: s_connect: connecting 198.61.189.25:5001
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 198.61.189.25:5001: waiting 10 seconds
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG5[0]: s_connect: connected 198.61.189.25:5001
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG5[0]: Service [remote] connected remote server from 192.168.0.12:57262
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: Remote socket (FD=9) initialized
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: SNI: sending servername: staging-fix.coinsetter.com
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server hello A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: Certificate verification disabled
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: Certificate verification disabled
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: Certificate verification disabled
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server certificate A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server key exchange A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read server done A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client key exchange A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write finished A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 flush data
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 read finished A
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]:      1 client connect(s) requested
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]:      1 client connect(s) succeeded
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]:      0 client renegotiation(s) requested
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]:      0 session reuse(s)
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG6[0]: SSL connected: new session negotiated
2015.09.23 23:11:40 LOG7[0]: Peer certificate was cached (871 bytes)
2015.09.23 23:11:41 LOG6[0]: Negotiated TLSv1.2 ciphersuite DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 (256-bit encryption)
2015.09.23 23:11:41 LOG7[0]: Compression: null, expansion: null
```

Comment: you can always run tcpdump to get plaintext data sent to stunnel

Comment: And received too?

Comment: **Yes. Yes. Yes.** Your program should use TCP to communicate with stunnel

Comment: Can you really TCPDUMP your loopback interface? Or I just need to send to my IP instead of to localhost?

Comment: @PeterMel Of course you can sniff the loopback interface, why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html). Even better, you can ditch stunnel and have socat do the SSL for you, e.g.,

```
socat -v TCP4-LISTEN:8888 SSL:198.61.189.25:5001
```

Comment: It would be a more useful answer if instead of just asserting you can do this with socat, you provided an example of what the logs would then look like. (Your example was for ditching stunnel, which wasn't the question asked.)